# Meteor Publish/Subscription Lag Time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, d3.js, meteor

I am using [d3](http://d3js.org/) to draw a meteor collection (Hostiles) with x and y coordinates onto an image. I can do this successfully. However, I have a publish function that checks to see if the user login is an admin or just a normal user. If the user is an admin it uses d3 to draw all of the points, but when it is any other user it only draws points specific to the user(s) location.

```
//Base Publish on User Type
if (user === true) {
  //Admin Return all Points
  return Hostiles.find();
} else {
  //Any other user returns location specific points 
  return Hostiles.find({latitude: {$lte: xLoc + 80, $gte: xLoc - 80}, longitude: {$lte: yLoc + 80, $gte: yLoc - 80}});
};
```

All of that works fine. The problem occurs when I change the `xLoc` and `yLoc` of a `Hostile` location. When the admin is logged in, the redraw is instantaneous with the change in the collection. However when a normal user is logged in there is a lag in redraw. This d3 redraw usually takes around 3-10 seconds. On the client I have both my subscription and d3 drawn in an `Meteor.autorun(function() {`. Maybe there isn't any way to get around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: And I am assuming that `xLoc` and `yLoc` are retrieved from the `Session`? Because if they are not, then the `autorun` would be executed only when some other reactive data source changes (or once every 10 seconds if the data in the Cursor changes, which might be what you are seeing).

Comment: Read this post on the Meteor blog: https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/12/17/meteor-070-scalable-database-queries-using-mongodb-oplog-instead-of-poll-and-diff - The current implementation of MongoDB's oplog only supports equality checks against scalar fields. All other operations (like your lte/gte checks) still use the old 10 second poll/diff method. This will change before 1.0, as the Meteor team adds more operators to the oplog implementation.

Comment: @musically_ut they are received using Session.

Comment: @Cuberto that makes a lot of sense, thanks. So until 1.0 I have to deal with the 10 second poll/diff method?

Comment: The SmartCollections package might work for you in the interim. They projected the release of 1.0 in early 2014, and that window is rapidly fading... Hopefully it will be coming soon.

Comment: You can try using the `oplog-with-operators` release which supports all selectors other than $where and $near.  See here for more details:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver

Comment: @alanning Ah, did not know about that. I wonder if there is a combined release for `oplog-with-operators` and `template-engine-preview-10.1`?

Comment: @Cuberto, I haven't seen any announcements about it, but yeah, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The current implementation of MongoDB's oplog only supports equality checks against scalar fields. All other operations (like your lte/gte checks) still use the old 10 second poll/diff method. This will change before 1.0, as the Meteor team adds more operators to the oplog implementation."-@Cuberto https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/12/17/meteor-070-scalable-database-queries-using-mongodb-oplog-instead-of-poll-and-diff

However there is a work around that is on the unreleased devel branch. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver . Which allows for the use of any selector supported by Minimongo not containing $where or $near . Simply use `meteor --release oplog-with-operators`. 
Thanks to @Cuberto and @alanning for the great solution.